# Распознание фотографий состоящих только из одного цвета

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не нашел доступного способа как распознать, что фотография состоит только из одного цвета. В приложении, которое я использую есть боты, которые входят в сообщество и ставят на фотографию зеленый цвет, фиолетовый и т.д. Я хочу их обнаруживать и автоматически банить. Подскажите может апи есть какое-то?

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - использовать библиотеку `Pillow`:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.jpg")

# Все различные цвета на фото
colors = im.getcolors()

if len(colors) == 1:
    print("бан")
else:
    print("не бан")
```

Comment: хмм, проверил на нескольких фото, с 1 цветом распознает, а если больше 1 - пишет len = NoneType has no len, т.е вообще нет цветов. Но со своей задачей вроде справляется

Comment: Нашел способ решения проблемы.
colors = im.getcolors(im.size[0]*im.size[1])